# PHP Check login attempts for 30 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I insert date(last attempts), attempts counter and ip into mysql database for control login attempts in my login page like this :

```
| id  |      ip       |   date     | attempts |
|  1  |  192.168.1.2  | 1412932824 |     5    |
```

Now in login page, i need to remove my form for 30 minutes if user attempts = 5.

MyCode:

```
$checkip = Access::FETCH("SELECT * FROM " . LOGIN_ATTEMPTS . "
                   WHERE
      ip = ? AND panel = ? ", _IS_GET_IP_ADDRESS_() , '1');

if (count($checkip > 0))
    {
    $time = new DateTime();
    $time->setTimestamp($checkip[0]['date']);
    $time->modify('+30 minutes');
    $timeattempts = $time->format('U');
    if ($checkip[0]['attempts'] <= 5 && $timeattempts < time())
        {
        // FORM SHOW
        }
    else
        {
        // SHOW ONLY ERROR
        }
    }
```

But this code notwork true for me and `$timestamp > time().`

How do fix my code for prevent login attempts?

**NOTE:** in action i update date(last attempts) and attempts for each login attempts.

Comment: you need to first of all show, how and when you insert / update the data in the database. additionally it's not clear what this number in the date column actually represents.

Comment: @hakre: i update date and attempts+1 for each existing ip.

Comment: and you update date with what?

Comment: @hakre: with `time();` for last attampts login.

Comment: have you tried to replace `&&` with `||` ?

Comment: @hakre: change all to `||`?

Comment: all? I only see one `&&` and that one, yes have you tried to change it to `||`?

Comment: i change ldo answer to `date >= ?` and this sork for me! thanks hakre for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do it only on the query:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("-30 minutes");
$checkip = Access::FETCH("SELECT * FROM " . LOGIN_ATTEMPTS . "
                          WHERE
                          ip = ? AND panel = ? AND attempts >= ? AND date <= ? ",
                          _IS_GET_IP_ADDRESS_() , '1', 5, $timestamp);

if (empty($checkip))
{
    // FORM SHOW
}
else
{
    // SHOW ONLY ERROR
}
```

Basically you searching for attempts that 5 or more, and the timestamp is not more then 30 minutes.
If you found it, then you don't want to show the login form.

Comment: i change ldo answer to date >= ? and this sork for me.